# jQuery EasyUI border layout - remove ability to collapse west

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

how do i remove the 'arrow' icon in the west panel. I want to prevent the user from collapsing the west?

```
<body class="easyui-layout">
        <div region="west" title="West" split="true" style="width: 200px;">
            <!-- WEST -->
        </div>
        <div region="center" title="center title" style="padding:5px;background:#eee;">
            <!-- CENTER -->
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add collapsible to false property to the west layout

The [document](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/layout.php) says:
collapsible - Defines if to show collapsible button.

```
<body class="easyui-layout">
    <div region="west" title="West" split="true" style="width: 200px;" collapsible="false">
        <!-- WEST -->
    </div>
    <div region="center" title="center title" style="padding:5px;background:#eee;">
        <!-- CENTER -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to remove the "title" attribute! Answered own qn.